# MAC Application hangs after some time

Tags: mac, cocoa

I am working on a MAC (Cocoa) application. It is a time tracking tool. It works fine for some time, but after 40 minutes the app gets slow, timer value not changes, UI responds very late. If i try to quit the app from dock i saw a message "App not responding".

How can i generate the cause of this issue?

Comment: "generate the cause"?  Perhaps you really want to "find a solution".

Comment: I don't know why its happening, i have checked through disk utilities also. I am an iOS developer and its my 1st mac app. So i am not able to fix this issue until i got the reason for this. So i need help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Often times, when applications get slow, its because they're leaking memory, which is not a problem you're going to be able to solve without access to the programmer's code.

You can give yourself more time with the application by freeing up as much working memory on your Mac as possible -- quite all apps you don't actively need.  Close browser windows, etc.

Open "Activity Monitor" to see a list of what's running on your Mac.  Double-click on the app's name, then take two samples, not too far apart in time.  Compare the resulting two files with "diff" (if your editor doesn't have this feature, the Mac's terminal does).  You may find an interesting lead there.

More simply, and more generally with commercial software, consult their support website or forum for similar problems &/or solutions from other users. Consider filing a bug, with as precise information as you can collect.